# Using if, else within recode

Tags: r, if-statement, recode

I am trying to replicate some code, but am running into trouble:

`data$var1` has values from 1-7 which I am trying to reduce to just 2 value in a new variable called `data$var2`. The code looks like this:

```
data$var2 <- recode(data$var1, "1:3=1; else=0")
```

However, when I execute code, I get the following error:

> "Error: Argument 2 must be named, not unnamed"

I'm working in the latest version of R and using the Tidyverse package.

What am I missing? What does 'Argument 2 unnamed'  mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise using `ifelse`:

```
data$var2 <- ifelse(data$var1 < 4, 1, 0)
```

Your use of `recode` is wrong:

```
data$var2<- recode(data$var1, "1:3=1; else=0")
```

Instead of several arguments `[name]=[replacement]` you provided only one string. For more information read `help('recode')`.

"Correct" way with `recode` would be something like

```
data$var2 <- recode(data$var1, `1` = 1, `2` = 1, `3` = 1, .default = 0)
```

But you should stick with `ifelse` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There are many to do this, probably many of them are easier than my approach.

```
 # Create some data
 df      <- c()
 df$var1 <- ceiling(runif(20, min = 0.5, max = 7.5))
 df$var1
 #  [1] 5 8 5 2 6 6 8 4 5 4 4 7 3 6 1 5 7 6 5 6

 # inds will contain TRUE/FALSE 
 inds           <- (df$var1 <= 3)
 df$var2[inds]  <- 1
 df$var2[!inds] <- 0
 df$var2
 # [1] 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

Sidenote: I used `df` as my object's name, because it is not a good idea to call objects `data`. The name `data` is reserved in R for other purposes (see `?data`). Even though in this case it will probably not lead to problems, I still recommend using `df` (or anything else) instead of `data`